# Android WebView cache aggressiveness

Tags: android, caching, android-webview

I developed a web app which I then embedded into an Android WebView. The problem I am encountering is that the WebView is barely doing any caching of assets compared to desktop Chrome for example.

As you can see, WebView barely caches anything ( only 2 entries here ), while desktop Chrome caches all of them.

WebView caching:
[image: WebView caching]
Chrome Desktop caching:
[image: Chrome Desktop caching]

What could be the cause of this and is there something I can do to make more things cached?

I have tried enabling AppCache with settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true), but that hasn't changed anything.

EDIT:
I believe that the cache is limited to 20MB, I have reduced the size of my web app to be under 20MB and now it's cached nicely. I have yet to find a way to increase that size limit.

Answer (score 1):

try to set [`setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK) on these `WebView` settings object

> Use cached resources when they are available, even if they have expired.

Comment: I have tried this and no luck. I believe that the cache is limited to 20MB, I have reduced the size of my web app to be under 20MB and now it's cached nicely. I have yet to find a way to increase that size limit.

Comment: What do you mean by 20 MB limit, is it the size of the android application ? Please help as I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the source code this is hard-coded to be 20MB and so unfortunately I don't think it can be increased.

```
static const int kMaximumCacheSizeBytes = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/jb-mr2-release/Source/WebKit/android/WebCoreSupport/WebCache.cpp