# Android Webview Cache not working in Cordova android app

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, caching, webview

I am developing a hybrid Cordova app where the webview cache is managed by the browser. However, the data from the API is not cached on subsequent requests. When I debug the Android app using chrome://inspect and check the network traces, it always fetches the data from the network instead of the disk cache. I have configured all the necessary webview settings related to cache, but it still doesn't work. I am using a Samsung Note 20 with Android version 13, although the issue is not specific to the OS version. I would appreciate your feedback on whether this is a limitation in Android.

The code to enable cache is as below:

```
 private void enableAppCache() {
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.appView.getView();
    if (myWebView != null) {
        myWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

My issue is similar like [Android WebView cache aggressiveness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71704544/android-webview-cache-aggressiveness).
Is there a limit to the app for which caching occurs? Please clarify.