# Stop re-rendering previous page on Android Webview

Tags: android-studio, webview, android-webview

I'm working on an Android WebView application, and I'm looking for a way to disable the automatic re-rendering of the previous page when the user navigates back within the WebView.

Here are the WebView settings I'm currently using:

```
        myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0; Pixel 2 Build/OPD3.170816.012) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Mobile Safari/537.36");
```

Currently, when the user presses the back button, the previous page gets re-rendered, unlike in Chrome where this behavior doesn't occur. I'm interested in a solution that involves capturing a snapshot of the previous page, navigating to it, and preventing the WebView from re-executing the entire rendering process. How can I achieve this effect in my Android WebView application?

So far, I've experimented with different WebView configurations, such as enabling caching and other similar adjustments, but unfortunately, none of these attempts have yielded the desired outcome.

Comment: Have you tried something like this?
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71704681/19386155)